# Drupal session issue

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules

I try to pass or redirect 1 item from a 'form', it's maybe not the best way to do by $_SESSION:

But, my problem is that the session on the specific page is empty. I clarify my explanation with code..

//store my drupal form table in the session, with var_dump() I can see the data. => `$_SESSION['sol_planning']` is not empty!

```
 function planning_view_page() {
//$sol_planning = $form['solution']['#sol'];
$_SESSION['sol_planning'] = $form['solution']['#sol'];
return $form; }
```

//On my other page, (where I want to display the table). the same session variable is null.

```
function planning_view() {
$sol_planning = $_SESSION['sol_planning'];
var_dump($sol_planning);
return $sol_planning;}
```

Have someone an explanation for this issue, I hope my question is clear.

Comment: try to ask that on http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [drupal session api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--session.inc/6) for this.

You can use `sess_write` and `sess_read`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `session_start()`